# MULE CXF proxy server to handle big xml requests with good performance

Tags: xml, soap, mule, cxf, xquery

I was looking for different approaches for developing a Proxy SOAP service in MULE that should be able to handle XML requests of size >500 MB. Since the files will be quite big in size and the requests frequency will be more, it need to perform well(I am talking about parsing the XML). I need to extract various nodes and attributes from the input XML. XQueryTransformer will be a good option?

Comment: It may be frustrating for you, but questions requesting recommendations for tools are out of scope on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry if my question confused you. I am not looking for tools. I am looking for a solution approach.

Comment: Sorry to have been confused.  I don't know how to interpret the question "XQueryTransformer will be a good option?" except as a question about tool choice.  Good luck.